Maven in Eclipse: How to make Eclipse show an error if repo is inaccessible/access token has expired
I have multiple Maven based projects in Eclipse and one of the main Maven remote repositories is a private Maven repo hosted in a GitLab project.
For accessing this Maven repository a working  Private-Token configuration entry has to be present in ~/.m2/settings.xml. Then everything works find. Problem is that GitLab access tokens can have a maximum life time of one year and then they expire and Maven looses access to the repo - but this is not displayed in Eclipse.
Is there a way to make Eclipse show an error if access to this repository is lost e.g. because authentication fails?
Maven built-in commands like Maven -> Update project (with enabled "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases) does not show any command-line output and if a repository not accessible Eclipse only shows a generic error that an artifact couldn't be resolved but no hint that this might be caused by an non-accessible repo.
